# Symfony using multiple translation files for single language

Tags: symfony

I was wondering if it is possible with Symfony 3.5 to use multiple translation files for a single language when using yml files.

Currently I have something like this:

```
AppBundle/Resources/translations/messages.en.yml
AppBundle/Resources/translations/messages.de.yml
```

which contains all my translations in either language. However I was wondering if it was possible to change this to the following structure:

```
AppBundle/Resources/translations/en/products.yml
AppBundle/Resources/translations/en/invoices.yml

AppBundle/Resources/translations/de/products.yml
AppBundle/Resources/translations/de/invoices.yml
```

I have been looking but I have been unable to find some kind of solution for this. I got it working for splitting up my routes.

```
AppBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml

appbundle_routes:
  resource: '@AppBundle/Resources/config/routing'
  type: directory
```

Inside that folder I got all my routes split like:

```
AppBundle/Resources/config/routing/products.yml
AppBundle/Resources/config/routing/users.yml
AppBundle/Resources/config/routing/invoices.yml
```

I was wondering if it was possible to achieve the same thing with translations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Symfony's `Translator` requires files to by named in format `domain.locale.loader`. In case you have `messages.en.yml`:

- `messages` is the default name of domain, you can also specify eg. `invoices`
- `en` is the locale
- `yml` is specifying `YAML` loader will be used

So your proposed use is not possible to achieve with standard set of configs and functionality. However, you can split your translations to different domain files. So paths would be:

```
AppBundle/Resources/translations/products.en.yml
AppBundle/Resources/translations/invoices.en.yml
```

And when you are using translator you specify the domain in which the translation should be looked for:

```
$translator->trans('translated.key', [], 'invoices');
```

Or in `Twig`:

```
{{ 'translated.key'|trans({},'invoices') }}
```

Comment: Ah thanks for the info, I suppose I'll have a look at this or end up writing my own translator service.